# Which team has gotten the most punishments for slow over rate?

Tags: cricket, icc, trivia

We know that [slow over rate](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/what-is-the-minimum-over-rate-for-a-fielding-team-in-international-matches) is an issue of the fielding team that can be punished by ICC.

In [June 2012](http://www.espncricinfo.com/magazine/content/story/605137.html) Misbah ul-Haq got punished (banned for one match) but their players didn't get that.

But in May 2012, England v West Indies, 1st Test, all the players of WI got [punishment](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-west-indies-2012/content/story/565733.html).

Which team has gotten the most punishments for slow over rate? I think it's possible to trace this out.

*Bonus question, if it's even possible to answer:* Which player has gotten the most punishments for slow over rate including overall formats of cricket?

Comment: Normally a player (the captain) get punishment for slow over rate. I didn't find any record though.

Answer (score 9):

I searched for different articles on low over rate punishment and found many article on ICC official website under search term low over rate, [Link to Website search result](https://www.icc-cricket.com/search?term=slow+over-rate). After manually checking many articles this is the result:

England has gotten the most punishments for slow over rate that is 18 occasion behind them is Sri Lanka with 17 times.

For player Mahela Jayawardene has most punishment until now that is 5 times between England and Sri Lanka, I would back this up after checking other countries as well.