# How many hours does a World Cup Cricket match usually last?

Tags: cricket, cricket-world-cup

The Cricket World Cup Final is tonight (3/28/2015) and it's starting at about 10:30pm central time in the United States. At about what time will it finish? I typically go to bed early and get up early, so I'm thinking maybe I can get up for the end, but I can't seem to find online how long an average final might last. I'd guess around 6 hours, but I'm not a huge fan of cricket by any stretch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be a large deviation of match length in the cricket world cup, consider the following two matches from the 2015 world cup:

- England bat first, are bowled out for 123 in 33 overs. New Zealand [knock off the runs](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-cricket-world-cup-2015/engine/match/656415.html?innings=1;view=commentary) in 12 overs. Match length: 4.5 hours (including tea break)
- Ireland score 331 in their 50 overs, losing 8 wickets. [Zimbabwe are all out for 326](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-cricket-world-cup-2015/engine/match/656457.html?innings=1;view=commentary) in the 50th over. Match length: about 8 hours.

In the end Australia won the final in [6 hours and 40 minutes](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-cricket-world-cup-2015/engine/match/656495.html?innings=1;view=commentary) (by my calculation), as they were able to chase down the New Zealand total of 183 with 17 overs to spare.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting **[This Answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2751/3737)**

> In ODI, 50 overs should be completed in 210 min as per the rules and out of this 10 min is provided for Drinks breaks.

And, `30-40 minutes innings break`.

Standard Case <sub>(Both teams bat 50 overs / Over rate is maintained by both teams)</sub>

In total two innings *(2x210)* + innings break, the match would go up to minimum **450 minutes i.e. 7.5 hours**.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia, "One-day cricket matches last for six hours or more".
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_time_%28cricket%29)

Comment: Thanks. I did see that, but is the Cricket World Cup format definitely identical to the one-day format?

Comment: Yes, the Cricket World Cup uses the ODI format. The rules are all but identical expect for some technical issues.

Answer (score -1):

Usually 8 hours is required for Completing a One ODI Match Of Cricket including innings break ..

The length doesn't matter at all . It takes to complete a 50 overs spell from both teamswhere each over includes six balls and If length takes longer than it required the team captain takes more times to complete spell of 50 over will charged as fine to his match fees